# Bluetooth adaptor is not working after disconnecting

Tags: android, bluetooth, adapter

I tested this malfunction by `Android 6.0`. But this situation is not regular. So I can't find a solution.

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

What I have done so far: 
I made some Application to connect to a custom device by Bluetooth.
I'm using both classic and Low Energy.
Sometimes Phone can't find the device. so I checked the `Logcat`.
It shows that Bluetooth adapter is not working. 
So the device can't search any device by Bluetooth.
But after turning `off/on` Bluetooth function or Rebooting the device.
It works very well.

It is a big problem that I can't find any pattern about this malfunction.

If you've seen the matter. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Are you using phone is Android N?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're calling `mBluetoothGatt.disconnect()` and `mBluetoothGatt.close();` on your BluetoothGatt instance when the app stops? It seems you have pending connection on the Bluetooth Adapter without having its reference inside your app. Can you post your code?